# How to check whether a Date parsed from Excel is in normal format (e.g. 01/01/2019) or in OA Date format?

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I use `OpenXml` to fill my database with values. One of my generic functions converts each cell's `value` (string) to a proper type:

```
convertedValue = Convert.ChangeType(value, realType);
```

Everything works fine unless it's a date. Sometimes `OpenXml` reads a date cell like this: `01/01/2019` and conversion works fine. Sometimes it converts to a number like this: `43466`. I know that this number represents how many days passed since 1900 but it breaks my function. It cannot convert this number to a `DateTime`.

I want to add a conversion for `OA Dates` like this:

```
convertedValue = DateTime.FromOADate(doubleValue);
```

The problem is how do I check that the value read from the cell is an `OA Date`?

I was thinking of checking the length of the `value` variable and verifing that all characters are numbers. Is there a better way to solve this problem?

Comment: I would try parse the datetime with `TryParseExact`. If it succeeds, its the normal date format. If it fails, create a DateTime at 1-1-1990 and add for example the `43466` to it using `AddDays(double days)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use TryParseExact to determine the format. If it doesn't parse exactly in the format provided, it will return false. Then we know we can use `FromOADate` method from DateTime

```
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(valueString, "mm/dd/yyyy", enUs, DateTimeStyles.None, out dateTime))
{
    // Handle standard date format
}
```